# Matplotlib subplot Background color not applying to the last graph in series

Tags: python, matplotlib, background-color, subplot

I am trying to set_facecolor() for my subplots in matplotlib and for some reason, these properties never apply to the last graph, there is no similar question to this hence, had to post the question for this. My code in Python for this is (I have just started coding in Python a couple of weeks ago, hence pardon my inefficient code, trying to solve the problem first) - [image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
city = 'Mumbai'
df = pd.read_excel (r'filename')
gg = df[df['City']==city]
x = gg['Date']
y1 = gg['Parks']
y2 = gg['Transit']
y3 = gg['Workplaces']
y4 = gg['Residential']
y5 = gg['Retail']
y6 = gg['Grocery']
fig,a =  plt.subplots(1,6,squeeze=False,figsize=(18,3),sharey=True)
fig.tight_layout(pad=0)
plt.box(on=None)
y = ""
plt.yticks(np.arange(-100, 101, 50))
a[0][0].set_ylim(top=50, bottom = -100)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace = 0.033)
for i in range(0,6):
    a[0][i].xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
    a[0][i].xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%b"))
    a[0][i].spines["top"].set_visible(False)
    a[0][i].spines["right"].set_visible(False)
    a[0][i].spines["bottom"].set_visible(False)
    a[0][i].spines["left"].set_visible(False)
    a[0][i].hlines(0,min(x), max(x),color='black', linewidth=0.5)
    a[0][i].set_facecolor('lightgrey')  
    #a[0][i].axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    if(i!=0):
        a[0][i].tick_params(left = False)
a[0][0].plot(x,y1)
a[0][1].plot(x,y2)
a[0][2].plot(x,y3)
a[0][3].plot(x,y4)
a[0][4].plot(x,y5)
a[0][5].plot(x,y6)

plt.show()
```

As you can see, the last plot is not having the background color as 'lightgrey'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `a[0][i].set_frame_on(True)` in front of (behind also works) `a[0][i].set_facecolor('lightgrey')`.